# Flex code doesnot(only sometimes) compiles in java+flex (+ BlazeDS+Tomcat ) combined project.a

Tags: java, performance, apache-flex, compilation, blazeds

i am working on a flex+java combined project.
My IDE and computer configuration is as follows:

```
   Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit, Core2Duo 2.1GHz, 2GB Ram
   Eclipse (helios) with Flash Builder Premium v4.0 Eclipse plugin
   Flex=javaEE combined project with BlazeDS v4.0.0.14931 and Apache Tomcat 6
   using BlazeDS remote object--RPC for flex+java communication.
```

**My Problem is :**

Any change in java code is compiled immediately and appeared on output when i run the project on server. 
When i make a small change in Flex code (eg, reposition of a button...anything), and run the project on server, it does make any change on output. 
Actually it depends on my luck... because it makes change in output randomly.
what is is happening???

i tried rebuild, republish, clean , restart server, restarting the IDE, restarting the computer..... all available feature i could think. Also, i created a simple flex project on IDE and compiled it..... everything is compiled and displayed on output.

**Please HELP ME.**

[Ganesh Tiwari](http://ganeshtiwari.com.np)

IOE, Pulchowk Campus, TU
Nepal

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear your browser cache and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Please clear the Browser Cache each time you run and then try.

SWF is cached by the browser, so it does not take the new one, it displays the old copy only.

Hope this should solve your problem